# formatting strings in lua in a pattern

Tags: lua, formatting

I want to make a script that takes any number, counts up to them and returns them in a format.
so like this

```
for i = 1,9 do
print(i)
end
```

will return

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

however I want it to print like this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and I want it to work even with things more than 9 so things like 20 would be like this

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
16 17 18
19 20
```

I'm sure it can be done using the string library in lua but I am not sure how to use that library.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function f(n,per_line)
  per_line = per_line or 3
  for i = 1,n do
    io.write(i,'\t')
    if i % per_line == 0 then io.write('\n') end
  end
end

f(9)
f(20)
```

Comment: Or combine the io.write() and if ... to: io.write(i,i % per_line == 0 and '\n' or '\t')

Answer (score 2):

The for loop takes an optional third *step*:

```
for i = 1, 9, 3 do
  print(string.format("%d %d %d", i, i + 1, i + 2))
end
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 2 ways to do this:

```
local NUMBER = 20
local str = {}
for i=1,NUMBER-3,3 do
    table.insert(str,i.." "..i+1 .." "..i+2)
end
local left = {}
for i=NUMBER-NUMBER%3+1,NUMBER do
    table.insert(left,i)
end
str = table.concat(str,"\n").."\n"..table.concat(left," ")
```

And another one using gsub:

```
local NUMBER = 20
local str = {}
for i=1,NUMBER do
    str[i] = i
end
-- Makes "1 2 3 4 ..."
str = table.concat(str," ")
-- Divides it per 3 numbers
-- "%d+ %d+ %d+" matches 3 numbers divided by spaces
-- (You can replace the spaces (including in concat) with "\t")
-- The (...) capture allows us to get those numbers as %1
-- The "%s?" at the end is to remove any trailing whitespace
-- (Else each line would be "N N N " instead of "N N N")
-- (Using the '?' as the last triplet might not have a space)
--    ^ e.g. NUMBER = 6 would make it end with "4 5 6"
-- The "%1\n" just gets us our numbers back and adds a newline
str = str:gsub("(%d+ %d+ %d+)%s?","%1\n")
print(str)
```

I've benchmarked both code snippets. The upper one is a tiny bit faster, although the difference is almost nothing:

```
Benchmarked using 10000 interations
NUMBER   20        20        20        100       100
Upper    256 ms    276 ms    260 ms    1129 ms   1114 ms
Lower    284 ms    280 ms    282 ms    1266 ms   1228 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary table to contain the values until you print them:

```
local temp = {}
local cols = 3

for i = 1,9 do
    if #temp == cols then
       print(table.unpack(temp))
        temp = {}
    end
    temp[#temp + 1] = i
end

--Last minute check for leftovers
if #temp > 0 then
    print(table.unpack(temp))
end
temp = nil
```